# Downloading specific Google Sheet as .CSV not working

Tags: google-sheets

So I have a Google Sheets file with multiple sheets. When I try to download as .CSV (File --> Download ---> .CSV) nothing happens but in previous weeks it was working fine. Downloading as .XLSX works. This issue only persists within this particular file (all other fines download as .CSV fine).

I have tried reopening the file and also I tried this across two separate days as I thought it might be a Google specific problem but to no avail.

Any idea what could be driving this?

Comment: Although I'm not sure about your actual situation, for example, when you copy your Spreadsheet and test it again using the copied Spreadsheet, what result will you obtain? If this was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in an incognito window or in a different web browser?

Comment: Copying the spreadsheet or using incognito generates the same issue of not being able to download .CSV. Other users in our Google workspace are also facing the same issue so it's not specific to my PC.

Comment: This is not an expected behavior from Google Drive. I would recommend contacting [Google Workspace support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213) for assistance if you have Google Workspace account, otherwise you can report your issue in the [Google's public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/).